# Implementation of PMKID computing function

Tags: hash, wpa2, hmac, pbkdf2

I am trying to implement a function, let's say in Python to compute Pairwise Master Key Identifier (**PMKID**) after reading the previously discovered bug in WPA2. Googling gave me this logical statement:

```
PMKID = HMAC-SHA1-128(PMK, "PMK Name" | MAC_AP | MAC_STA)
```

However, the problem is i am not able to compute the right hash. I've tried various possibilities, tried converting data to binary, tried various versions of MAC but still no chance.

The Question is how do I implement the function for computing PMKID, preferably in Python. Here's what i've doing a bit:

```
import hashlib, binascii, hmac
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2

print "Required hash: 2a416a999af0a6bf454684269afb06ef"
apmac = '34:bf:90:4a:bb:57'
clmac = '98:de:d0:1a:97:c2'
pmk = PBKDF2('786 5555', 'unknown', 4096).read(32)
print "PMK: "+binascii.hexlify(pmk)
pmkid = hmac.new(pmk, "PMK Name"+apmac+clmac, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
print pmkid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, but you need to put the MACs in hex:

'\x34\xbf\x90\x4a\xbb\x57' instead of '34:bf:90:4a:bb:57'

Comment: Your answer is right. However, it's late now. I've figured this out after spending another day on google.